# New line not exported in beeline dsv output

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

I want to export the output of an SQL query into a csv file.

```
HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Ddisable.quoting.for.sv=false -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" beeline -u $JDBC_URL --silent=true --outputformat=dsv --delimiterForDSV=';' --verbose=false --hiveconf hive.query.tag=${tag} -f query.sql > output.csv
```

The query might output **string values with new line characters '\n'** (i.e. multiple lines values), but all these new line characters are missing in the output .csv file.

When I set `disable.quoting.for.sv=true`, it keeps the new line characters, but the output file has a bad .csv format as the csv delimiters are not escaped.

It seems like enabling quoting for separated values removes all new line characters '\n'.

Is there a way to output a **valid .csv file** and still get all the new line characters in it ?

---

What my .csv output looks like :

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| val1 | "This is; a line.Another line" | val2 |
| val3 | "Hi" | val4 |

What I want :

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| val1 | "This is; a line. Another line" | val2 |
| val3 | "Hi" | val4 |

*Note: the SQL query outputs "This is a line.\nAnother line"*

Comment: Made a typo, just edited the question to add "col3" in "What I have now"

Comment: What do you mean by "separators are not escaped"? Like, there's no `\n` characters?

Comment: No I meant to say that the CSV delimiters (here semi colons) are not escaped from input strings with `disable.quoting.for.sv` set to True. Resulting in bad csv format.

Comment: That setting isn't going to quote the delimiters. The sv stands for "single value", I believe. I want to say there's a different config for preserving newlines, and it's disabled by default, anyway https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=30758725#HiveServer2Clients-Quotingincsv2,tsv2anddsvFormats  The semicolons don't need escaped. They'll only be contained in the quotes of a column if there's a semicolon within, rather than between columns, as the docs mention

Comment: I'm pretty sure sv stands for "separated value", no ?. Your link is not working for me :/ I'm stuck on a loading page.
The problem is not really with the option `disable.quoting.for.sv` as it needs to stay at False (which is the default value). I think that somehow beeline removes each new line characters (`\n`) from the output in order to get a valid .csv (which should not be compulsory) ...

Comment: Ah, you're right. Docs do say separated value. And sorry, that was from my phone - try [this link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-Separated-ValueOutputFormats)